# liquibase unable to create index and unique constraint on partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, docker, liquibase

Liquibase file is as below :

databaseChangeLog:

```
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: roran
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: account_balance
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: bigint
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
              - column:
                  name: account_id
                  type: bigint
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: balance_date
                  type: date
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
              - column:
                  name: create_date
                  type: timestamptz
              - column:
                  name: created_by
                  type: varchar(100)
              - column:
                  name: update_date
                  type: timestamptz
              - column:
                  name: updated_by
                  type: varchar(100)
        - modifySql:
            applyToRollback: false
            dbms: postgresql
            append:
              value: PARTITION BY RANGE (balance_date);
        - addUniqueConstraint:
            columnNames:  balance_date, account_id
            tableName:  account_balance
        - createIndex:
            columns:
              - column:
                  name:  account_id
            indexName:  account_id_idx
            tableName:  account_balance
```

I am getting below error on adding unique constraint while starting spring boot application

> Migration failed for change set /db/changelog/changes/1.create-account-balance-table.yml::1::roran:     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near PARTITION  Position: 93 [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE public.account_balance ADD UNIQUE (balance_date, account_id)PARTITION BY RANGE (balance_date);]\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)\

Similarly, I am getting error on adding index while starting spring boot application.

> liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/changes/1.create-account-balance-table.yml::1::roran:     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near PARTITION  Position:  [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE INDEX account_id_idx ON public.account_balance_p0(account_id)PARTITION BY RANGE (balance_date); CREATE TABLE public.account_balance_p0 PARTITION OF account_balance FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-10-01 00:00:00') TO ('2020-11-01 00:00:00');]\tat liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:646)\tat liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53)\tat liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)\tat liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)\tat

Same is working fine , if I create table via liquibase and later programmatically if i create index or add constraint as below

```
CREATE INDEX account_id_idx ON public.account_balance(account_id);
```

Is there any error the way I am using yaml in liquibase for partitioned table?

I am using postgresql 11 version and liquibase with spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `modifySql` Type of your `ChangeSet` is applied to your `addUniqueConstraint` and `createIndex` Types as well. The exception of the generated sql occurs due to the addition of the `PARTITION BY RANGE` to the `Index` and `UniqueConstraint` creation.

Just split it in 2 parts - one ChangeSet with the table creation and one ChangeSet with the `Index` and `UniqueConstraint` creation:

```
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: roran
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: account_balance
            columns:
              ...
        - modifySql:
            applyToRollback: false
            dbms: postgresql
            append:
              value: PARTITION BY RANGE (balance_date);
```

and

```
  - changeSet:
      id: 2
      author: roran
      changes:
        - addUniqueConstraint:
            columnNames:  balance_date, account_id
            tableName:  account_balance
        - createIndex:
            columns:
              column:
                name:  account_id
            indexName:  account_id_idx
            tableName:  account_balance
```